# Adding stylesheets for an internal page only

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to add a CSS file to a specific internal basic page in Drupal 7 with no success.
After enabling the clean URL paths and add a path for my internal basic page I am able to capture the path using `$path=drupal_get_path_alias();`.

After that, I am trying to put condition statements so when a specific path is loaded a specific CSS file is loaded. I have this piece of code in `ninesixty_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook)` in the template.php file.

```
if($path == 'about/advantages') {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'ninesixty') . "/page-about.css");
}
```

I have tested the IF-statement by echoing the `$path` variable with total success. The page-about.css file does not load at all, though.

Please note that I am using Drupal with WAMP server, and the page-about.css file is located under drupal/sites/all/themes/ninesixty/styles/framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path is incorrect; it should be as in the following code.

```
if ($path == 'about/advantages') {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'ninesixty') . "/styles/framework/page-about.css"); 
}
```

Comment: Reminding of accepting an answer could be fine, but asking also an up-vote is a bit more: Accepting an answer is giving an up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

For adding CSS files to specific pages, you can use the [CSS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) module.

> Allows administrators to inject CSS into the page output based on configurable rules. It's useful for adding simple CSS tweaks without modifying a site's official theme—for example, a 'nighttime' color scheme could be added during certain hours. The CSS is added using Drupal's standard `drupal_add_css()` function and respects page caching, etc.
>
> This module is definitely not a replacement for full-fledged theming, but it provides site administrators with a quick and easy way of tweaking things without diving into full-fledged theme hacking.

Comment: I was hoping to do that myself and not use a module. :) so any other suggestion?